# How would I rewrite the formula for torsion in terms of arc length $s$ into a formula in terms of a general parameter $t$?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry

The torsion of a parametrized space curve is defined in terms of arc length $s$ as

$$\tau = -\frac{d\mathbf B}{ds} \cdot \mathbf N(s).$$

I'm trying to come up with a formula for torsion in terms of a general parameter $t$ along with a proof. I know I can use the chain rule to get 
$$\frac{d\mathbf B}{ds} = \frac{d\mathbf B}{ds}\frac{ds}{dt}.$$
But how can I rewrite $N(s)$ at $N(t)$?

I feel like I can't just replace $N(s)$ with $N(t)$ as these are different functions.  Would I divide by the speed?  What would the new formula for torsion be written completely in terms of a general parameter $t$?  Can you include a quick proof?

Also... I've been taking screenshots to include mathematical notation when posting in stackexchange.  Can someone give me a link with instructions on how to write math notation using stackexchange syntax?  Please forgive my lack of knowledge on the matter.

Edit 1:  To be more clear, Curvature is defined in terms of arc length as 
$$\kappa (s) = |\mathbf T'(s)|$$

But we can rewrite it in term of a general parameter $t$ as

$$\kappa(t) = \frac{|\mathbf T'(t)|}{|v(t)|}.$$

I'm looking for a way to do this with torsion.  I hope this clarifies my question.  I do know there are alternate formulas.  But I'm looking for this type of derivation for torsion specifically.

Edit 3:  After thinking about it a bit, if we know the function $s(t)$ then would this work?  It seems everything is now defined in terms of $t$ now so I'm thinking it would.

$$\tau(t) = - \frac{d\mathbf B}{dt}\frac{ds}{dt} \cdot \mathbf N(s(t))$$

Comment: $$\tau=\frac{(\gamma'\times\gamma'')\cdot\gamma'''}{\left\|\gamma'\times\gamma''\right\|^2}$$

Comment: Thanks DonAntonio.  I know this formula, however I'm looking for something else. I edited my question to make it more clear.

Comment: @Mi As far as I remember, and even after a quick search, I don't think there's something similar to what you want.

Comment: I see.  I took at stab at it in my third edit.  It makes sense to me... but I sometimes miss things.  What do you think?

Comment: See [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for a tutorial on how to use math notation in your posts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're very close, but you have the chain rule wrong. The correct form of the chain rule is this:
$$\frac{\frac{d\mathbf B}{dt}}{\frac{ds}{dt}} = \frac{d\mathbf B}{ds}(s(t)) = -\tau(s(t)) \mathbf N(s(t)).$$
In practice, everything is written just as functions of $t$.

Comment: Yes that was a typo.  Thank you for confirming!

Comment: So I was thinking more about this.  I would need to find arc length s in terms of time t to use this formula.  How would I do this?  This doesn't seem like something you would typically be given in problem.  Maybe that's why we have that alternate formula like the one that Don Anontio gave above?

Comment: No, not at all. You only need $ds/dt$, which is the speed.

Comment: @MichaelMcCain: If you want to see lots of examples of this technique (along with plenty more exercises), help yourself to my free differential geometry text. The link is in my profile. (Sadly, most of the published texts don't emphasize the power of the chain rule nearly enough.)

Comment: I see.  But the formula above requires s(t) and not s'(t).  I can find s'(t) easily by finding the magnitude of the velocity vector.  So finding s(t) would require finding the indefinite integral of s'(t) and then solving for C.  I would need an initial condition right?  It doesn't seem like this is something that I would typically be given in a problem.  What do you think?

Comment: Oh and thank you for the textbook link.  I will definitely check it out!

Comment: @Michael: No, we just write $s(t)$ to be pedantic. In the real world, you're just working with everything as a function of $t$ from the get-go, and you don't care what $s(t)$ actually is. Check out the examples in my text.